# jQuery validation - Textbox requires data if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have a checkbox - `HasRaffle` that will require a textbox - `RaffleItem` to contain data if `HasRaffle` is checked.  How would I do this?  I've never done my own jQuery validations before.  This is what I attempted, but it's not working at all.  Am I even close?

```
$("#donationEventForm").validate({
    rules: {
        RaffleItem: {
            required: function () {
                if ($("#HasRaffle").is(":checked")) {
                    if ($("#RaffleItem").val === '') {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            messages: {
                required: "This is a test!!"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: Here's my View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "DonationEvent", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "donationEventForm"})) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Charity)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Charity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Charity)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new {@class = "datepicker"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new {@class = "datepicker"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.Label("Raffle?")
        @Html.CheckBox("HasRaffle", true)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RaffleItem)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RaffleItem)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RaffleItem)
    </div>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GLCode, new {@type = "hidden"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TransactionDescription, new {@type = "hidden"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreatedBy, new {@type = "hidden"})

    <div class="form-field-buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='../Home/Index'"/>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: This is only half of the picture.  Also show the HTML for your form.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a custom rule with addMethod

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkRaffle', function(value, element){
    if ($("#HasRaffle").is(":checked")) {
        if (value === '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, 'Please write something')
```

Then the rule would look something like that :

```
rules: {
    'RaffleItem': {
        'checkRaffle' : true
    }
}
```

This code is not tested (and will probly not work becuase i cant see your DOM), BUT if you can see the logic behind my code you can probably debug your!